# Computing the expectation of the number of balls in a box

Tags: probability-theory

> - There are $r$ boxes and $n$ balls.
> - Each ball is placed in a box with equal probability, independently of the other balls.
> - For each $1 \leq i\leq r$, let $X_{i}$ be the number of balls in box $i$.
> - Compute $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}\right],\ \mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}X_{j}\right]$.

I am preparing for an exam, and I have no idea how to approach this problem. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Symmetry reasoning makes it clear that $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}\right]$ doesn't depend on $i$. Likewise, $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}X_{j}\right]$ doesn't depend on the concrete values of $i$ and $j$ but only (if at all) on whether $i=j$ or $i\neq j$. But this doesn't actually compute these expectations.

Comment: Have you studied covariance matrices, or vector-valued random variables, at all?  That would seem to me to provide the most compact notation for solving this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are $r$ boxes and $n$ balls, and each ball is placed in a box with equal probability, we have:

$$ \mathbb{E}[X_i] = \frac{n}{r} $$

Now, we would like to know what is $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] $.

We begin by making the following observation:

$$X_i = n - \sum_{j\neq i}X_j $$

Which gives us:

$$ X_i\sum_{j\neq i}X_j = nX_i - X_i^2$$

Now, fix $i$ (we can do this because of the symmetry in the question), and thus we have:

\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] &= \frac{1}{r}\Big(\mathbb{E}[X_i \sum_{j\neq i} X_j] + \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{r} \mathbb{E}[nX_i] \\
&= \frac{n^2}{r^2}
\end{align}

Comment: If indeed $E(X_i X_j) = E(X_i) E(X_j)$ for $i \in j$ then that implies zero correlation.  I would expect a bit of negative correlation.  (And indeed, my preliminary calculation based on the decomposition from VHarisop's answer seems to result in $E(X_i X_j) = \frac{n(n-1)}{r^2}$ for $i \ne j$ and $E(X_i^2) = \frac{n}{r} + \frac{n(n-1)}{r^2}$.)

Comment: Yeah, it seemed a little strange to me initially, but its consistent with your results btw: $\frac{1}{r}[(r-1)E(X_iX_j) + E(X_i^2)] = \frac{n^2}{r^2}$

Comment: I've now expanded VHarisop's answer with my calculations for part two of the question.

Comment: I can't follow your last computation: How do you get the first equality sign? The answer also doesn't match @VHarisop's answer, which looks correct to me.

Comment: @darijgrinberg sorry the first equality of which part?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] = \frac{1}{r}\Big(\mathbb{E}[X_i \sum_{j\neq i} X_j] + \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]\Big)$. How do you get that?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Oh that’s just the definition of expected value? An average over all possible values of $X_i X_j $.

Comment: Huh? How does $X_i ^2$ get into that average?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Because choosing two indices $i,j$where $i=j$ is also a possibility?

Comment: Let me ask it differently: why do you get a different answer than VHarisop?

Comment: @darijgrinberg sorry for the late reply - I believe it’s because VHarisop doesn’t include the case where he considers $i=j$. His should be correct when $i \neq j$

Comment: But yours is then wrong in that case, right?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yup

Comment: Then please say this in your answer... at the moment it's rather misleading. Or are you considering $i $ and $j $ to be sampled uniformly too? I suspect OP wants them constant.

Answer (score 6):

For the first part, you can use linearity of expectation to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$. 
Specifically, you know that for a fixed box, the probability of putting a ball in it
is $\frac{1}{r}$. Let

$$
Y_k^{(i)} = \begin{cases}
   1 &, \text{ if ball $k$ was placed in box $i$} \\
   0 &, \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases},
$$
which satisfies $\mathbb{E}[Y_k^{(i)}] = \mathbb{P}(Y_k^{(i)} = 1) = \frac{1}{r}.$
Then you can write

$$
X_i = \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j^{(i)} \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}X_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{r} = \frac{n}{r}.
$$

---

For the second part, you can proceed similarly: $X_i = \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k^{(i)}$ and $X_j = \sum_{\ell=1}^n Y_{\ell}^{(j)}$, so:
$$
X_i X_j = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n Y_k^{(i)} Y_{\ell}^{(j)} \implies
\mathbb{E}(X_i X_j) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n \mathbb{E}(Y_k^{(i)} Y_{\ell}^{(j)}).
$$
We will first treat the case where $i \ne j$.  Then, for each term in the sum such that $k = \ell$, we must have $Y_k^{(i)} Y_{\ell}^{(j)} = Y_k^{(i)} Y_k^{(j)} = 0$ since it impossible for ball $k$ to be placed both in box $i$ and in box $j$.  On the other hand, if $k \ne \ell$, then the events corresponding to $Y_k^{(i)}$ and $Y_{\ell}^{(j)}$ are independent since the placement of balls $k$ and $\ell$ are independent, which implies that $Y_k^{(i)}$ and $Y_{\ell}^{(j)}$ are independent random variables.  Therefore, in this case,
$$\mathbb{E}(Y_k^{(i)} Y_{\ell}^{(j)}) = \mathbb{E}(Y_k^{(i)}) \mathbb{E}(Y_{\ell}^{(j)}) = \frac{1}{r} \cdot \frac{1}{r}.$$
In summary, if $i \ne j$, then
$$\mathbb{E}(X_i X_j) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n \delta_{k \ne \ell} \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{r^2}$$
where $\delta_{k \ne \ell}$ represents the indicator value which is 1 when $k \ne \ell$ and 0 when $k = \ell$.

For the case $i = j$, I will leave the similar computation of $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2)$ to you, with just the hint that the difference is in the expected value of $\mathbb{E}(Y_k^{(i)} Y_{\ell}^{(j)})$ for the case $k = \ell$.

Comment: I decided to add my solution to part two, using your notation, to your answer to avoid having an answer split between your part and a part I would post separately.  Feel free to edit it more to your liking, or even revert the addition if you prefer.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Looks good, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Think of placing the ball in box "$i$" as success and not placing it as a failure.

This situation can be represented using the [Hypergeometric Distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)
$$
P(X=k) = \frac{{K \choose k} {N- K\choose n - k}}{{N \choose n}}.
$$

$N$ is the population size (number of boxes $r$)

$K$ is the number of success states in  the population (just $1$ because the success is defined as placing the ball in box "$i$".)

$n$ is the number of draws (the number of balls $n$).

$k$ is the number of observed successes (the number of balls in box "$i$").

The expectation of the Hypergeometric Distribution is $n\frac{K}N$, hence the mean of your variable 
$$E[X_i]=n\frac{1}{r}=\frac{n}{r}$$